# Tree data to flat data in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012

I am facing the problem tree view to flat view, I have some data that has come from a tree, those are stored in a table that is presenting in my picture below left. I am saying the top level of tree is level1, and second level is level2 and so on. My expected result that is representing in my picture below right.

[image]

How can I convert my data to my expected result dynamically in SQL Server? We have to create dynamic column level1, level2, level3 and so on. Do you have any idea? Thanks.

Here is the sample data

```
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#TestData', 'U') IS NOT NULL 
DROP TABLE #TestData;

CREATE TABLE #TestData (
    Id INT NOT NULL,
    SomeName VARCHAR(3) NOT NULL,
    ParentId INT NULL 
    );
INSERT #TestData (Id, SomeName, ParentId) VALUES 
    (1, 'O', NULL),
    (2, 'D1', 1),
    (3, 'D2', 1),
    (4, 'S1', 2),
    (5, 'S2', 2),
    (6, 'S1', 3),
    (7, 'SP1', 3);

SELECT * FROM #TestData td;
```

Comment: Post the sample data as text in table format instead of image..

Comment: Recursive query + dynamic pivot. Look around and try to implement.

Comment: @EvaldasBuinauskas, thank you.

Comment: Downvote reason: You've been here long enough and have enough reputation to know how to ask a good question. The least you can do is creating ddl + dml for sample data.

Comment: @ZoharPeled, Thanks for your guideline.

Comment: Downvote retracted.

Comment: @ZoharPeled, wow great, thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#TreeData', 'U') IS NOT NULL 
DROP TABLE #TreeData;

CREATE TABLE #TreeData (
    Id INT NOT NULL,
    SomeName VARCHAR(3) NOT NULL,
    ParentId INT NULL 
    );
INSERT #TreeData (Id, SomeName, ParentId) VALUES 
    (1, 'O', NULL),
    (2, 'D1', 1),
    (3, 'D2', 1),
    (4, 'S1', 2),
    (5, 'S2', 2),
    (6, 'S1', 3),
    (7, 'SP1', 3);

--SELECT * FROM #TestData td;

;With Cte as (   --Recursive CTE for traversing tree
    Select Id,SomeName,ParentId, convert(varchar(max),[SomeName]) as NameLevel, 1 as Levl from #TreeData where ParentId is Null
    Union all
    Select t.Id, t.[SomeName], t.[ParentId],  (c.NameLevel +','+ t.[SomeName]) as NameLevel, c.Levl + convert(int, 1) as Levl 
     from Cte c
          inner join #TreeData t on c.Id = t.ParentId
)
--select * from cte
Select * from ( 
    select c.Id, c.Levl, a.Items
    ,RowN = row_number() over(partition by Id order by Levl) from cte c
    cross apply  split(c.NameLevel,',') a
) sq
pivot(max([Items]) for RowN in([1],[2],[3])) p --Pivot for getting all data
```

Answer (score 2):

You can query as below:

```
;With Cte as (   --Recursive CTE for traversing tree
    Select *, convert(varchar(max),[name]) as NameLevel, 1 as Levl from #TreeData where ParentId is Null
    Union all
    Select t.Id, t.[Name], t.[ParentId], concat(c.NameLevel,',',t.[name]) as NameLevel, c.Levl + 1 as Levl  from Cte c
        inner join #TreeData t on c.Id = t.ParentId
)
Select * from ( 
    select c.Id, c.Levl, a.[value]
    ,RowN = row_number() over(partition by Id order by Levl) from cte c
    cross apply  string_split(c.NameLevel,',') a
) sq
pivot(max([value]) for RowN in([1],[2],[3])) p --Pivot for getting all data
```

Output as below:

```
+---+------+------+----+
| 1 |  2   |  3   | Id |
+---+------+------+----+
| O | NULL | NULL |  1 |
| O | D1   | NULL |  2 |
| O | D2   | NULL |  3 |
| O | D1   | S1   |  4 |
| O | D1   | S2   |  5 |
| O | D2   | S1   |  6 |
| O | D2   | SP1  |  7 |
+---+------+------+----+
```

Below the input table and data I used:

```
Create Table #TreeData(Id int, [name] varchar(10), ParentId int)

Insert into #TreeData(id, [name], ParentId) values
 (1,'O', null)
,(2,'D1',   1)
,(3,'D2',   1)
,(4,'S1',   2)
,(5,'S2',   2)
,(6,'S1',   3)
,(7,'SP1',  3)
```

Comment: Hi, I am getting the error ---- Types don't match between the anchor and the recursive part in column "NameLevel" of recursive query "Cte".

Comment: Could you give me full example according to my sample data

Comment: Updated input table and data

Answer (score 1):

The following should give you the requested results.

Note: This solution relies on the use of an iTVF called tfn_Tally, I'll post the code for that below my answer.

```
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#TestData', 'U') IS NOT NULL 
DROP TABLE #TestData;

CREATE TABLE #TestData (
    Id INT NOT NULL,
    SomeName VARCHAR(3) NOT NULL,
    ParentId INT NULL 
    );
INSERT #TestData (Id, SomeName, ParentId) VALUES 
    (1, 'O', NULL),
    (2, 'D1', 1),
    (3, 'D2', 1),
    (4, 'S1', 2),
    (5, 'S2', 2),
    (6, 'S1', 3),
    (7, 'SP1', 3);

--  SELECT * FROM #TestData td;

--===========================================
--===========================================

IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#RecursionResults', 'U') IS NOT NULL 
DROP TABLE #RecursionResults;

WITH 
    cte_Recursion AS (
        SELECT 
            td.Id, 
            SomeName = CAST(CAST(td.SomeName AS BINARY(5)) AS VARBINARY(1000)),
            --td.ParentId,
            NodeLevel = 1
        FROM
            #TestData td
        WHERE 
            td.ParentId IS NULL
        UNION ALL
        SELECT 
            td.Id,
            SomeName = CAST(CONCAT(r.SomeName, CAST(td.SomeName AS BINARY(5))) AS VARBINARY(1000)),
            NodeLevel = r.NodeLevel + 1
        FROM
            cte_Recursion r
            JOIN #TestData td
                ON r.Id = td.ParentId
        )
SELECT 
    Id = ISNULL(r.Id, 0), r.SomeName, r.NodeLevel
    INTO #RecursionResults
FROM
    cte_Recursion r;

-- adding a clustered index Id eliminates the sort operation on final select.
ALTER TABLE #RecursionResults ADD PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED (Id);

-----------------------------------------

DECLARE 
    @PivotCount INT = (SELECT MAX(rr.NodeLevel) FROM #RecursionResults rr),
    @PivotCols VARCHAR(1000) = '',
    @PivotCAV VARCHAR(8000) = '',
    @sql VARCHAR(8000),
    @Debug BIT = 0;     -- set to 0 to execute, 1 to DeBug.

SELECT TOP (@PivotCount)
    @PivotCols = CONCAT(@PivotCols, CHAR(13), CHAR(10), CHAR(9), 'L', t.n, '.Level_', t.n, ','),
    @PivotCAV = CONCAT(@PivotCAV, CHAR(13), CHAR(10), CHAR(9), 'CROSS APPLY ( VALUES (CAST(SUBSTRING(rr.SomeName,', (t.n - 1) * 5 + 1, ', ', 5, ') AS VARCHAR(5))) ) L', t.n, ' (Level_', t.n, ')'
        )
FROM 
    dbo.tfn_Tally(@PivotCount, 1) t;

SET @sql = CONCAT('
SELECT ', 
    STUFF(@PivotCols, 1, 1, ''), '
    rr.Id
FROM 
    #RecursionResults rr',
    @PivotCAV, '
ORDER BY 
    rr.Id;');

IF @Debug = 1
BEGIN
    PRINT(@sql);
END;
ELSE
BEGIN 
    EXEC (@sql);
END;
```

Function code for tfn_Tally...

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.tfn_Tally
/* ============================================================================
07/20/2017 JL, Created. Capable of creating a sequense of rows 
                ranging from -10,000,000,000,000,000 to 10,000,000,000,000,000
============================================================================ */
(
    @NumOfRows BIGINT,
    @StartWith BIGINT 
)
RETURNS TABLE WITH SCHEMABINDING AS 
RETURN
    WITH 
        cte_n1 (n) AS (SELECT 1 FROM (VALUES (1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1)) n (n)),   -- 10 rows
        cte_n2 (n) AS (SELECT 1 FROM cte_n1 a CROSS JOIN cte_n1 b),                             -- 100 rows
        cte_n3 (n) AS (SELECT 1 FROM cte_n2 a CROSS JOIN cte_n2 b),                             -- 10,000 rows
        cte_n4 (n) AS (SELECT 1 FROM cte_n3 a CROSS JOIN cte_n3 b),                             -- 100,000,000 rows
        cte_Tally (n) AS (
            SELECT TOP (@NumOfRows)
                (ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) - 1) + @StartWith
            FROM 
                cte_n4 a CROSS JOIN cte_n4 b                                                    -- 10,000,000,000,000,000 rows
            )
    SELECT 
        t.n
    FROM 
        cte_Tally t;
GO
```

HTH,
Jason

Comment: Thanks for your answer

Comment: Well... Before you plagiarize my test data and mark another answer as correct, you may want to add some new levels to the test data. You requested that the solution dynamically pivot the data... Of the 3 solutions offered, mine is the only one that will pivot the data dynamically.

Comment: Do not worry brother. Kannan Kandasamy answer is better than you. I have given a vote for all.